# Marshaling compose c/c++ structure in c#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

I need to solve this problem. I have structure (StructA) which contains pointer to second structure. The second structure has integer variable.

In code below I have C procedure(GetStrucure()). I want to set integer value into variable ValB in StructB. StructA contains pointer to StructB. GetStrucure() returns StructA. This works correctly.

In C# code I want to call GetStrucure() form C dll. ValA is returned correctly but ValB return incorrect value 3207020. Why is value from pointer not correct?

```c
struct StructB
{
   int ValB;
};

struct StructA
{   
   StructB* S;
   int ValA;
};
```

and procedure:

```c
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) StructA GetStrucure() 
    {   
        StructA sA;
        StructB sB;
        sB.ValB = 5;    

        sA.S = &sB;
        sA.ValA = 6;
        return sA;
    }
}
```

and C# code:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential]   
public struct StructA
{        
    public StructB S;
    public int ValA;        
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct StructB
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
   public int ValB;
}

class Program
{
   [DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   static extern StructA GetStrucure();        

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      StructA a = GetStrucure();            
   }
}
```

I too tried

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential]   
public struct StructA
{        
    public IntPtr S;
    public int ValA;        
}
```

and

```cs
StructB b = (StructB)Marshal.PtrToStructure(a.S, typeof(StructB));
```

But I got different nonsensical value...

Please can any body help me?

Comment: It is standard UB, a [dangling pointer bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), sA.S refers to a local variable whose lifetime ends when the function returns.  Tends to go unnoticed in a C program, if you're lucky, but definitely misbehaves in C# when the stack frames used by the pinvoke marshaler code overwrite the memory formerly occupied by the old stack frame.

Comment: This requires a major redesign.  The memory management is too painful to consider keeping the StructB*, both in C and C#, consider `StructB S` instead.

Comment: Thank you. And what if is StructB pointer to linked list? Is it possible or redesign requires?